# Differnce between circuits in graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Given a full undirected graph with 3 vertices: $v1, v2, v3$ and $3$ edges.
Is there any differnce between those 2 cycles:

$C1: v1-{(e1)}-v2-{(e2)}-v3-{(e3)}-v1$

$C2: v2-{(e1)}-v3-{(e2)}-v1-{(e3)}-v2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example we just have two different traversals of the same cycle.

A cycle is completely determined by the edges it includes. In an undirected graph we may traverse the cycle in two different directions and starting at any of the vertices or edges in the cycle, but different traversals don't give different cycles. Note that in a directed graph we have the same thing except we can only traverse the cycle in a single direction.